# login using ssh on multiple user accounts using the same id_rsa and id_rsa.pub

Tags: linux, ssh

i have an `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` . say i have 5 users on the same machine. i want to use the same `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` to ssh between users without password. is it possible ? As i figure it out if user1 wants to do `ssh user2@localhost` ...`/home/user2/.ssh` must have a file named `authorized_keys` with the content of `id_rsa.pub`. and `/home/user1/.ssh` must have the id_rsa file. so by doing this user1 can do `ssh user2@localhost`.
But if user2 wants to do `ssh user1@localhost` then user1 must have the `authorized_keys` having the contents of `id_rsa.pub` and user2 must have the `id_rsa` file

to sum it up user1 has : `authorized_key, id_rsa` and user2 has the same files.
what happens on my machine is: user1 can do `ssh user2@localhost` but user2 cannot do `user1@localhost`.

is there something missing ? is there something i do not understand ? is it possible to ssh between users using the same `id_rsa` and the same `id_rsa.pub` ?

Comment: Can user1 do `ssh user1@localhost`?  I ask because it could be a permissions problem on `/home/user1/.ssh` or the authorized_keys file therein

Comment: That should just work, yes. To simplify the set-up, you might want to use the `ssh-copy-id` command to install the keys. Also, check that the private key for user2 is not readable, and check your system logs for messages from sshd. It usually puts something in there if it dislikes the permissions.

Comment: Agreed - it should work.

Comment: i just deleted authorized_key, id_rsa from both user1/.ssh and user2/.ssh and recopied id_rsa and copied and renamed id_rsa.pub to authorized_key. so now both users have again the same setup. but now i can't ssh at all. for user1 it asks the password and for user2 it asks the passphrase. uhm... i gave the files the 600 permissions

Comment: i just used ssh-copy-id and user1 can again log in to user2. but still user2 cannot login to user1. from all 5 users user1 seems to be able to login only to user2

Comment: @John11 600 perms on `authorized_keys` isn't enough.  `/home/user/.ssh` needs to be 700.  Also if you copied the files around, ensure that the ownership is correct too.  `chown -R user1:user1 /home/user1/.ssh` and same for user2.

Comment: forgot about ownership ... will try it .. thanks

Comment: If it works, I'll copy my comment into an answer.

Comment: nope, seems like user1/.ssh was owned entirely by user1 and the same goes for user2.
there is however a difference in the user1/.ssh permissions and user2/.ssh.
user1/.ssh has drwxr--r--
while user has drwxr-xr-x

Comment: `/home/user/.ssh` directories cannot be other- readable or executable.  You have to `chmod 700 /home/user2/.ssh`.  You didn't answer before - can user1 ssh as himself `ssh user1@localhost`?

Comment: user1 cannot ssh to himself ... now every .ssh for every user has 700 perm.

Comment: @John11 And all the `authorized_keys` files have correct ownership and 600 perms now?  If user1 can't ssh to himself, I still suspect bad permissions.  Also be sure to @Michael in your comments so they show in my inbox.  I'll see them sooner.

Comment: To debug this you MUST examine what's in the security log -- on Redhat is's /var/log/secure, but is probably in a different place in other distros.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the advice. i finally got it working. seems that i mixed up some things and was not aware of. now all five users can ssh each and everyone of them including themselves. 
So in case anyone else needs this i will say what was wrong... 
i actually managed to change the ownership of one of the users (user2) and on another user the ownership of the autherized_keys was not the user in whose directory it was.
in short whatever you have in user1 must belong to user1 and whatever you have in user2 must belong to user2 and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Michael also the perms. must be just as Michael and the others have said. on ubuntu I used /var/log/auth.log to debug messages about sshd. Michael if you want you could make a summary of what you said before about perms and ownership and ssh-ing to itself and write an answer. Also take into consideration that there may be others that screwed up the ownerships as i did. Thanks again.

Comment: @John11 I'll add a summary of my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File permissions on a user's `/home/user/.ssh` directory must be `700`, and the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` must be `600`.  Meanwhile, it is essential that all files in each `.ssh` directory are owned by the user in whose home directory they reside.  To change ownership recursively, you can:

```
chown -R username:username /home/username/.ssh
```

If you have multiple users and need to do this for each of them, you can use this loop:

```
for SSHUSER in user1 user2 user3 user4 user5; do
  # Add the authorized_keys file if it doesn't already exist
  touch /home/$SSHUSER/.ssh/authorized_keys

  # Set its permissions
  chmod 600 /home/$SSHUSER/.ssh/authorized_keys

  # Set directory permissions
  chmod 700 /home/$SSHUSER/.ssh

  # Set ownership for everything
  chown -R $SSHUSER:$SSHUSER /home/$SSHUSER/.ssh
done;
```

Comment: Also first check the permissions on `/home/$SSHUSER`. Make sure it's - `755`; `777` didn't work for me.